# wrong bytearray of a document in office taskpane app using office365 javascript API

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps

I am trying to retrieve the byte array of the current document, when using the office 365 taskpane app in Word 2013 on the local computer.

In order to get the the byte array, I used the msdn example from [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync)

The byte array looks ok on the first look, but after converting it back to a document i get following error message when trying to open the document in Word:

> We're sorry. We can't open document.docx because we found a problem with its contents.
>   Details: The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.

I did a test with a Node server, to convert the same document to a byte array, and compare the arrays for changes, and noticed small changes between the values of the array. ([see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cevzq.jpg))

did anyone else encounter this kind of issue? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried converting the binary to a base64? I modified the onGotAllSlices method to convert the fileContent to base64 (stored in mybase64 variable) and then i used [this](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) web app to encode it back to binary (saved it as docx, basically) and i was successfully able to open the resulting  file.

here is the code (just added the last line to get the base64 :) )

```js
 function onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices) {
        var docdata = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
            docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
        }

        var fileContent = new String();
        for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
            fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
        }
       
        // var textFileAsBlob = new Blob(docdataSlices, { type: contentType });


        var mybase64 = window.btoa(fileContent);
        // Now all the file content is stored in 'fileContent' variable,
        // you can do something with it, such as print, fax...
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this solution brought me on the right track.I needed the byte array of the file for uploading the file to another service using the API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Juan's answer i managed to find a solution to my issue.

For some unknown reasons the byte array that was returned by the office 365 API was not complete, but after converting it to a base64 and then back to binary, did the trick.

```js
var onGotAllSlices = function(docdataSlices, callback) {
  var docdata = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
    docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
  }

  var fileContent = new String();
  for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
    fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
  }
  //convert to base64
  var base64 = window.btoa(fileContent);

  // convert it back to binary
  var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
  var len = binaryString.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
    bytes[k] = binaryString.charCodeAt(k);
  }

  callback(bytes);
};
```

in the callback function, now I could upload the byte array to another server or save it locally.